# lwc:if does not work with @api properties

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have noticed `lwc:if` does not work with `@api` attributes.

Has anyone faced this? Also is there a documentation where this is mentioned.

HTML:

```
<template>

    <div class="container">
        <article class="slds-card">
            <template lwc:if={boolShowCustomFilter}>
                <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                    <div class="slds-modal__container">
                        <!-- modal header start -->
                        <header class="slds-modal__header">
                            <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={hideModalBox}>
                                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                                                alternative-text="close"
                                                variant="inverse"
                                                size="small"></lightning-icon>
                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                            </button>
                            <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Edit Filters</h2>
                        </header>

                        <!-- modal body start -->
                        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                            <div class={strTableCustomFilterClass} lwc:dom="manual"></div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- modal footer start-->
                        <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                            <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={hideModalBox}>Cancel</button>
                            <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={hideModalBox}>Ok</button>
                        </footer>

                    </div>
                </section>
                <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
            </template>
        </article>
    </div>

</template>
```

JS:

```
@api boolShowCustomFilter = false;


handleCustomSearch(){
    this.boolShowCustomFilter = true;
}

hideModalBox(){
    this.boolShowCustomFilter = false;
}
```

As soon as the page loads it shows this modal. But if I remove `@api` it works fine, i.e after clicking of  `handleCustomSearch()`

Comment: I used it with `@api` attributes without any issue. Are those attributes primitive? Could you share the code?

Comment: Yes, updated the question with code. Yes, those are primitive data types only. Only if I remove `@api` it works fine.

Comment: Could you please share also the parent component code where that attribute is setted? Anyway if the modal should be showed only after clicking `handleCustomSearch()`, why not decorate it with `@api` (if it's called from a parent component) and remove the decorator from the `boolShowCustomFilter` attribute?

Comment: there is no Parent component, this modal sits down in DOM and gets enabled after clicking the button. This `@api` issue I faced because `boolShowCustomFilter` earlier was declared as `api`, I can remove it no issues, but was just checking if anyone has faced this

Comment: @NagendraSingh Could you try to replicate the issue with a simpler example and share here? :)

Comment: @Raul I tried doing it in lwc studio https://app.lwc.studio/edit/yEz8A0V9p8gWWb63GU9G/src/app.js?p=stories, but seems like lwc studio is not yet into latest LWC framework, as it does not recognize lwc:if yet and throws `LWC1127: Invalid directive "$lwc:if" on element <template>.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@api` properties are read-only within the component. Previously, the runtime would allow this, but a recent update enforces this read-only behavior. If you need a property you can update internally, consider:

```
_showCustomFilter = false;
@api set showCustomFilter(value) {
  this._showCustomFilter = !!value; // Convert truthy to true/false
}
get showCustomFilter() {
  return this._showCustomFilter;
}
```

In your template, use the non-public property:

```
lwc:if={_showCustomFilter}
```

Note that I'm recommending that you drop the Hungarian notation. It's a relic of an ancient past. Adding the prefix doesn't add any information that isn't already obvious from the property's name.