# LWC - @api property does not render on child component

Tags: lightning-web-components, error, parent-to-child, custom-event

I have a 4 layers LWC component: great-grandparent > grandparent > parent > child. I want to pass an @api property from great-grandparent to display and modify data in child.

Because the property does not display on the parent component so please excuse me for posting the code of grandparent and parent only.

`Great-Grandparent Controller`

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Sobject> getDatas(Boolean isRecentlyView, 
                                         List<String> fields, 
                                         String sobjectType, 
                                         String query, 
                                         Integer limitNum){
        try {
            if (limitNum != null) {
                if (isRecentlyView) {
                    query = 'SELECT ' + String.join(fields, ', ') + ' FROM ' + sobjectType + ' WHERE LastViewedDate !=null ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC ';
                    query += ' LIMIT :limitNum';
                } else {
                    query = query.split('FROM')[1];
                    query = 'SELECT ' + String.join(fields, ', ') + ' FROM ' +  query;
                    query += ' LIMIT :limitNum';
                }
                return Database.query(query);
            } else return new List<SObject>();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

`Great-Grandparent HTML`

```
<c-grandparent data={parentdata}></c-grandparent>
```

`Great-Grandparent JS`

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getDatas from '@salesforce/apex/ListviewController.getDatas';

export default class Great-Grandparent LightningElement {

@api limitNum; // receiving value from config xml

@track isLoading = false;
@track fieldcolumns = [];

parentdata = [];
numberOfRecords = '';
isRecentlyView = false;

handleGetData(){
    getDatas({
       isRecentlyView: this.isRecentlyView,
       fields: fields,
       sobjectType: this.sObjectType,
       query: query,
       limitNum: this.numberOfRecords})
       .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            this.parentdata = result;})
       .catch(e => {
            console.error(e);})
     }
}
```

`Grandparent HTML`

```
<c-parent records={data}
   onlistitemdrag={handleListItemDrag}
   onitemdrop={handleItemDrop}>
</c-parent>
```

`Grandparent JS`

```
@api data // I have not performed any logic for it here, so I only post the property
```

`Parent HTML`

```
<template>
    <ul ondrop={handleDrop}
        ondragover={handleDragOver}
        style="height:70vh; overflow-y:auto;">
        <template for:each={records} for:item="recordItem">
            <c-child record={recordItem} 
                key={recordItem.Id}
                onitemdrag={handleItemDrag}>
            </c-child>
        </template>
    </ul>
</template>
```

`Parent JS`

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Parent extends LightningElement {
    @api records;

    renderedCallback() {
        console.log("Render call back in parent"); //I log to see how it render
        console.log('this.records',this.records);
    }

    handleDragOver(evt){
        evt.preventDefault()
    }

    handleDrop(){
        //some logic here
        this.dispatchEvent(event)
    }

    handleItemDrag(evt){
        //some logic here
        this.dispatchEvent(event)
    }

}
```

=== I tried another way to approach it by update enforces this read-only behavior ===

- Reference resource: `lwc:if does not work with @api property` [lwc:if does not work with @api properties](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/398745/lwcif-does-not-work-with-api-properties)

`Parent HTML Modified Code`

```
<template>
    <ul ondrop={handleDrop}
        ondragover={handleDragOver}
        style="height:70vh; overflow-y:auto;">
        <template for:each={_records} for:item="recordItem">
            <c-child record={recordItem} 
                key={recordItem.Id}
                onitemdrag={handleItemDrag}>
            </c-child>
        </template>
    </ul>
</template>
```

`Parent JS Modified Code`

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Parent extends LightningElement {
    _records = [];

    get records() {
        return this._records;
    }
    @api set records(value) {
        this._records = value;
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        console.log("Render call back in parent"); //I log to see how it render
        console.log('this._records',this._records);
    }

    handleDragOver(evt){
        evt.preventDefault()
    }

    handleDrop(){
        //some logic here
        this.dispatchEvent(event)
    }

    handleItemDrag(evt){
        //some logic here
        this.dispatchEvent(event)
    }
}
```

`Result from debug console`

```
this.records 
Proxy(Array)
[[Handler]]: ReadOnlyHandler
[[Target]]: Array(5)
length: 5
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

Thank you so much for taking a look at my code

Comment: What's the relevant code for the great-grandparent? Depending on that's written, it may explain why parent is having problems.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, I posted additional code for Great-Grandparent. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numberOfRecords = '';
```

Isn't a valid number, so your Apex Code won't parse it correctly, and end up with a null value.

```
if (limitNum != null) {
  // ...
} else return new List<SObject>();
```

Since `limitNum` is null here, you'll return an empty list.

Thus, you don't get any results, and nothing appears at the parent level.

To fix this, provide a valid number.

```
numberOfRecords = 100;
```

Further, you probably want to use `connectedCallback()` to call your method, rather than putting in the class body as a function. This code shouldn't compile at all.

```
connectedCallback() {
  getDatas({
   isRecentlyView: this.isRecentlyView,
   fields: fields,
   sobjectType: this.sObjectType,
   query: query,
   limitNum: this.numberOfRecords})
   .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.parentdata = result;})
   .catch(e => {
        console.error(e);})
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, I'm sorry for not posting enough. I've just refined my code and add result from debug console. => I call apex method inside a function instead of connectedCallBack => limitnum get passed from config xml file so it will never be null

Comment: Thank you for your answer and refinements. I found out the problem is because of the way data is passed in my code. It will be lost after a user clicks save.

@api (public) attribute works fine. No problem about it.